# SonarQube - Include files for test coverage, exclude for analysis

Tags: sonarqube

I have some generated code (JavaScript from TypeScript) that I don't want analysing by sonar (for bugs etc), but I do want the test coverage including.

Currently by using the Sonar inclusion/exclusion we have the coverage and the bugs.

Sonar v6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to ignore all rules on all files using the "Analysis Scope > Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria" settings on your project.

Please read ["Narrowing the focus"](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/narrowing-the-focus.html) on the official documentation.

Comment: That worked. I did read the docs originally, but skipped over the bit saying you could wildcard the rules! Looking at the underlying db, would you discourage setting the same values via properties in our gradle build script. 
`property "sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria", "1"`
`property "sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.1.ruleKey", "*"`
`property "sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.1.resourceKey", "src/main/webapp/resources/js_compiled/**"`

Comment: Yes we discourage this, simply because the underlying way to store those multi-value property sets might change w/o notice.

Answer (score 0):

I used the above solution. Thank you for that. Just adding this as an alternative by simplifying writing tests for Pojos like this:

- Java: https://www.pojo.pl/writing-tests/
- Js: ?